# Obtaining all values from a table but with distinct RunID

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a table called MyTable that contains the following column headers

- MachineID
- RunID
- Time

The table looks something kind of like this

[image]

What I want to do with my query is to group by RunID but still show MachineID. That way I can get something like this

[image]

I have tried something like this

```
MyTable
| distinct RunID
```

But that only shows the distinct runId, I also want to show the MachineID associated with it and I'm not sure of how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the machine ID as another aggregation key, e.g.

```
datatable(machine_id:int, run_id:int, timestamp:datetime)
[
    1, 4321, datetime(2021-04-13 01:00),
    1, 4321, datetime(2021-04-13 01:01),
    1, 7654, datetime(2021-04-13 12:00),
    1, 7654, datetime(2021-04-13 12:01),
    2, 5667, datetime(2021-04-13 02:30),
    2, 5667, datetime(2021-04-13 02:31),
    3, 4867, datetime(2021-04-13 04:30),
    4, 2430, datetime(2021-04-13 05:00),
    4, 2430, datetime(2021-04-13 05:01),
    4, 2430, datetime(2021-04-13 05:02),
]
| distinct machine_id, run_id
```

```
machine_id  run_id
----------  ------
1           4321
1           7654
2           5667
3           4867
4           2430
```

Comment: Thank You! what would I have to do if I wanted to add times to this? (as all times are different for a single run _id)

Comment: you may want to clarify _which_ times you'd like to add. preferably, for the input you've provided - provide the required output